# What were the arguments Hawking considered naive against imaginary time?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics

### background

So I recently I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AImaginary_time#Comments_by_Michael_Hardy).

> I believe that you are correct; I think an inclusion of that might
>   make the article a bit clearer. Hawking used that explanation to
>   rebuke a naive philosopher's attacks on imaginary time as a
>   "mathematical trick with nothing to do with the 'real world'".
>   However, it is sort of hard to tell exactly what it means for real
>   time to correspond to real numbers and for imaginary time to
>   correspond to complex/imaginary numbers.

And this

> There are two very important aspects of imaginary time that are not
>   mentioned. 1) imaginary (or Euclidean) time corresponds to equilibrium
>   thermodynamics: if a system is held at a temperature T, one can set
>   time= i /( k_B T ) where i is the imaginary number 2) Making this
>   transformation converts the Schroedinger equation , which has wave
>   solutions into a diffusion-like equation. This is much easier to
>   calculate with and is the basis for most numerical methods to treat
>   quantum systems with more than 3 particles. see articles on lattice
>   guage theory or quantum monte carlo. These two aspects are of great
>   practical importance in our understanding of quantum systems.

### Question

**What were these "naive"** **(as considered by stephen)** **arguments used by philosophers?** What are some (other) **possible counter (to imaginary time) arguments a philosopher can use**? I'm searching for references - since the mainstream physics community doesn't side with hawking ([atleast anymore](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2016/11/15/einstein-and-hawking-had-different-ideas-about-the-concept-of-imaginary-time/))

Comment: This is from a wiki talk over the [Imaginary Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_time) article, and "naive philosophers" are an allusion to the quote from Hawking's Universe in a Nutshell. Except there he just says:"*One might think this means that imaginary numbers are just a mathematical game having nothing to do with the real world. From the viewpoint of positivist philosophy, however, one cannot determine what is real.*" So there are no "arguments" or "naive philosophers" in particular, this is just a turn of phrase convenient for Hawking to make his point.

Comment: @Conifold I was the impression Hawking engaged with some philosophers who might have said something against his ideology. Was hoping for something along the lines of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw6hS_gy9MY and Hawking disliked

Comment: @Conifold This is what hawking was going on about: " “Philosophers have not kept up with modern developments in science. Particularly physics." - https://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/google/8520033/Stephen-Hawking-tells-Google-philosophy-is-dead.html . I'm not sure which school of philosophers gave Hawking such a bad impression.

Comment: Also edited the question to include: "What are some (other) possible counter (to imaginary time) arguments a philosopher can use?"

Comment: Yes this statement by Hawking has come up before here at Philosophy SE.  Hawking should not have made such a sweeping statement as this.

Comment: What he says in the Telegraph interview is not specific to "imaginary time", or anything else. His chief complaint is that philosophy doesn't tackle "big questions" as it used to, addressed at it all and nobody in particular. If you are interested in a philosophical critique of the Hartle-Hawking proposal see e.g. [Emerging from Imaginary Time by Deltete and Guy](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20117541), but Hawking himself seems completely unaware of philosophical discussions on the subject.

Comment: @Conifold yes I am interested in the link you provide. I'd love to reward (bounty) an existing answer but for now it's a comment :/